# jquery ajax call to MVC controller failing

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

The Chrome debugger is showing the name as "GetPurchaseOrdersComponent" and the path as "/Cost", whereas calls made by Telerik grid controls have the name "4485" and path "/Cost/GetPurchaseOrders" (and they are working). Also, the type on my call (when viewed in Chrome's debugger) is text/html, whereas on the working calls, it's application/json. The error I'm getting is: "500 (Internal Server Error)". I have a similar route defined for this call as for the other calls. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Cost/GetPurchaseOrdersComponent",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        data: { id: 1 },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#ComponentsMultiLevelGrid").html(result);
        }
    });


[HttpGet]
public string GetPurchaseOrdersComponent(int id)
{
     return "some string";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's the header from a call that works (this call is from a Telerik grid):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:61751/Cost/GetSupplierCatalogs/4485?key=4485&_=1340830508447
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

**Request Headers** - view source
Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:13
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=uxn1ctvzcchyrbreymcgz1vl
Host:localhost:61751
Origin:http://localhost:61751
Referer:http://localhost:61751/Transaction/4485
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

**Query String Parameters** - view URL encoded
key:4485
_:1340830508447
Form Dataview URL encoded
page:1
size:5

**Response Headers** - view source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:21
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 27 Jun 2012 20:55:28 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
```

Here's the header from the call that's failing (this is the jQuery call):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:61751/Cost/GetPurchaseOrdersComponent?id=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

**Request Headers** - view source
Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=uxn1ctvzcchyrbreymcgz1vl
Host:localhost:61751
Referer:http://localhost:61751/Transaction/4485
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

**Query String Parameters** - view URL encoded
id:1

**Response Headers** - view source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:10434
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 27 Jun 2012 20:55:25 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Comment: Since you are returning a "string", you need to change the dataType: to "text".

Comment: Changing that didn't fix the error 500, although I see that was a change that needed to be made, so thanks.

Comment: I tested your code with the dataType='text' and it worked on a local server. The suggested way to reference a MVC 3 url is to use the @Url.Content("~/Cost/GetPurchaseOrdersComponent"), You may also want to put a break-point on the return "some string" statement and add an "error: function(a,b,c) {...}" to the ajax call.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference. Also, I've tried putting a breakpoint in the method in the controller. The call never even makes it that far. I added header info to the question above, in case that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Don't ask me why.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPurchaseOrdersComponent", "Cost", new { id = ViewBag.CustomerEstimateKey })',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ComponentsMultiLevelGrid").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: The reason yours works is because he is returning a string and you used dataType:"text", but he had specified dataType:"json...".  The string "some string" is not valid json, and thus would fail to parse.

Answer (score 1):

JSON requests work with `POST` only, so you need to use the correct verb and also you need to send a JSON request because that's what you have specified in the `contentType` parameter. This is achieved with the `JSON.stringify` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Cost/GetPurchaseOrdersComponent",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ComponentsMultiLevelGrid").html(result);
    }
});
```

or if you don't want to use a JSON request get rid of the `contentType` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Cost/GetPurchaseOrdersComponent",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    data: { id: 1 },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ComponentsMultiLevelGrid").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your second example is actually what I had originally. I don't care about using json. I just need to get that integer into the method in my controller. Adding the contentType param was just something I tried. I've also tried the json example with a POST and it still didn't work.

Comment: By the way, here's the route, but as I said, it's no different than the ones that are working with the Telerik grids:             routes.MapRoute(null, "Cost/GetPurchaseOrdersComponent/{id}", new { controller = "Cost", action = "GetPurchaseOrdersComponent" });